# Sum and aggregate over a list with equal values

Tags: python, list

I have a pair lists of the same length, the first containing `int` values and the second contains `float` values. I wish to replace these with another pair of lists which may be shorter, but still have the same length, in which the first list will contain only unique values, and the second list will contain the sums for each matching value. That is, if the i'th element of the first list in the new pair is `x`, and the indices in the first list of the original pair in which `x` has appeared are `i_1,...,i_k`, then the i'th element of the second list in the new pair should contain the sum of the values in indices `i_1,...,i_k` in the second list of the original pair.

An example will clarify.

Input:

```
([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0])
```

Ourput:

```
([1, 2, 3], [1.0, 0.5, 1.0])
```

I was trying to do some list comprehension trick here but failed. I can write a silly loop function for that, but I believe there should be something much nicer here.

Comment: It was quite difficult to phrase the question properly in the title, any edits are welcome.

Comment: Can we see your silly loop function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a one-liner, but since you've not posted your solution I'll suggest this solution that is using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a, b = ([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0])
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for k, v in zip(a, b):
...     d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v
...     
>>> d.keys(), d.values()
([1, 2, 3], [1.0, 0.5, 1.0])
```

Of course if order doesn't matter then it's better to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a, b = ([1, 'foo', 'foo', 1, 1, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0])
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k, v in zip(a, b):
    d[k] +=  + v
...     
>>> d.keys(), d.values()
([3, 1, 'foo'], [1.0, 1.0, 0.5])
```

Comment: I started writing it, but you were faster... that isn't that bad, actually. Have you used OrderedDict so `keys` and `values` will have the same order? Isn't that de-facto guaranteed in `dict` as well?

Comment: @Bach Yes, it is guaranteed in normal dict as well. But I thought order was important for you looking at your output, so used `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 3):

one way to go is using `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'tag':[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3], 
                       'val':[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0]})
>>> df
   tag  val
0    1  0.1
1    2  0.2
2    2  0.3
3    1  0.4
4    1  0.5
5    3  1.0
>>> df.groupby('tag')['val'].aggregate('sum')
tag
1      1.0
2      0.5
3      1.0
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice, but a little bit of an overkill, isn't it?

Comment: @Bach yes, it may be an over-kill depending on what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Build a map with the keys:

```
la,lb = ([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0])
m = {k:0.0 for k in la}
```

And fill it with the summations:

```
for i in xrange(len(lb)):
    m[la[i]] += lb[i]
```

Finally, from your map:

```
zip(*[(k,m[k]) for k in m]*1)
```